# 2 lines 3 inline-blocks div breaking at different resolutions

Tags: css

I need 3 inline-blocks divs in each of two lines.

I do use `inline-block`, width `220` and height `80`.

At different resolutions it breaks the alignment some blocks go to the top.

How can I force the alignment with 3 blocks inline into each of two lines (6 divs 3 per line).

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem "some blocks go to the top"?  Can you post your code? Thanks!

Comment: .buttoncenter {
  background-image: url(../../images/base.png); 
  width: 222px !important; 
  height: 145px !important;
  text-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:8px;
  position: relative;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `whitespace` property of CSS. Give the `inline-block` container, the following CSS:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put

```
font-size: 0;
```

in the parent wrapper, the reason might be that the sum of width from your div(s) is equal or bigger than 100% of its parent, and if you put every children div onto a new line, there's a small space between it. That explained this fix

```
<div>
  content
<div>
<div>
  content
</div>
```

into

```
<div>
  content
</div><div>
  content
</div>
```